# Как выполнить несколько проверок введенных пользователем данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо проверить введенные пользователем данные.
Есть такой код на python

```
while True:
    try:
        input_data = int(input("Введите число: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова: ")
```

Код проверяет, что ввели именно число. А как теперь сделать проверку, чтобы число лежало в диапазоне 10 <= input_data <=50?

Comment: Думаю, что в питоне тоже есть конструкция `if-then-else`.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python 3. Проверка на целое число—условие на проверку данных, введенных пользователем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585259/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, конечно, понимаю, что в python считается нормальным реализовывать через обработку исключений много такого, на что в других языках пишут явные проверки. Философия EAFP и всё такое.

Но проверять с помощью исключений числовой тип - это уже даже для питона лютый изврат.

Делайте так:

```
while True:
    input_data = input("Введите число: ")
    if not input_data.isnumeric():
        print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова: ")
    elif not 10 <= int(input_data) <= 50:
        print("Ваше число не диапазоне. Попробуйте снова")
    else:
        print("Число в правильном диапазоне.")
        break
```

Comment: Ваш код наглядно демонстрирует почему код в вопросе совершенно корректно использует ValueError (вот ответ @Tox это уже перегиб: "выбрасывать и ловить *на том же уровне*" лучше избегать). Что int принимает и что isnumeric возвращает это разные вещи (подумайте, что isdigit, isdecimal делают для Юникодных строк).

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш способ рабочий.

Comment: @alex_t: `'¾'.isnumeric()` возвращает `True`. Не используйте, `isnumeric()`, если вы всё равно строку в `int()` сразу же передаёте (`int('¾')` выбрасывает ошибку). Можно заплатку ввиде `isdecimal()`, использовать, но чтобы в тонкости Unicode стандарта не вникать, [используйте EAFP подход: сразу передаёте строку в int и обрабатывайте ожидаемые ошибки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571866/23044).

Answer (score 2):

Просто выполняйте проверку одну за другой:

```
def input_int_in_range(start, end):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Введите число: "))            
        except ValueError:
            print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова.")    
        else:
            if start <= n < end:
                return n
            print("Введённое число вне диапазона: [%d, %d)" % (start, end))
```

Пример:

```
n = input_int_in_range(10, 50 + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получается как-то так

```
while True:
    try:
        input_data = int(input("Введите число: "))
        if 10 <= input_data <= 50:
            print('OK')
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("Вы ввели не число или число не входит в указанный диапазаон. Попробуйте снова: ")
```

Comment: Подряд `raise ValueError` и тут же `except ValueError` в той же функции—не лучший способ код организовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
def input_(msg):
    input_data = input(msg)
    if not input_data.isdigit(): return input_("Вы ввели не число. Введите число: ")
    if 10 <= int(input_data) <= 50: return input_data
    return input_("Ваше число не диапазоне. Введите число:")
print(input_("Введите число: "))
```

out:

```
Введите число: фыв
Вы ввели не число. Введите число: 121
Ваше число не диапазоне. Введите число:22
22
```

Comment: `'\xb2'.isdigit()` возвращает `True`, хотя `int('\xb2')` выбрасывает ошибку. [Используйте EAFP подход](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571718/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/571843#comment794482_571741)