# Как запретить вводить числа

Tags: python-3.x

Как запретить вводить числа?

Например:

```
name = input('Введите имя')
number = input('Введите номер')
```

Чтобы где переменная `name` там запретить вводить числа, а где переменная `number` запретить вводить слова.

Comment: http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/articles/programming/python_foolproof.phtml

Comment: можно ввод числа не запрещать, а потом все числа "вынуть" иэ строки

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как выполнить несколько проверок введенных пользователем данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571718/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

i=False
while not i: # Цикл будет выполняться пока i не станет True
    name = input('Введите имя ')
    if re.findall(r'\d', name)==[]: # re.findall(r'\d', name) вернет список из цифр которые используються в значении переменой name, если цифры не использовались вернеться пустой список
        i=True
        print("Данные введены верно")
    else: print("Данные введены неверно, попробуйте еще раз")
i=False
while not i:
    number = input('Введите номер ')
    if re.findall(r'\D', number)==[]: # re.findall(r'\D', name) вернет список из букв которые используються в значении переменой number, если цифры не использовались вернеться пустой список
        i=True
        print("Данные введены верно")
    else: print("Данные введены неверно, попробуйте еще раз")
```

Comment: 1- Вместо `re.findall(r'\d', name)==[]`, стоит использовать: `not re.search(r'\d', name)`. 2- вместо `while not i: ... i=True`, можно просто `while True: ... break` написать

Answer (score 0):

Проверяет на основе исключение TypeError, ValueError.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
try:
    number = int(input())
    print(number,'является целым числом')
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print('Не является целым числом')
```

Так же можно проверить методом isinstance:

```
tryname = isinstance(name, str)
trynumber = isinstance(number, int)
if tryname == True:
    print('ok')
elif tryname == False:
    print('error')
if trynumber == True:
    print('ok')
elif trynumber == False:
    print('bad')
```

Comment: 1- подход c try/except в правильном направлении. Стоит пользователю предоставить возможность повторить ввод в случае ошибки ([просто цикл добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571866/23044)). 2-
 `isinstance()` здесь совершенно бесполезен (`input()` в Питоне 3 никогда `int` не вернёт)

Comment: `TypeError` здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
name.isalpha()  # содержит ли строка только буквы - bool
number.isnumeric()  # содержит ли строка только числа - bool
''.join(s for s in name if not s.isnumeric())  # удалить все числа
''.join(s for s in number if s.isnumeric())  # удалить все не числа
```

Comment: не используйте `isnumeric()` для проверки того что число (принимаемое `int()`) было введено. [Эта функция работает не так как вы думаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571718/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85#comment794482_571741)