# Проверка значения при вводе

Tags: python, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить проверку значения  при вводе n. При n > 20 должна происходить остановка программы. Делал всяческие перестановки с циклом и if, ничего путного не вышло.
Задача на Схему Горнера([условие задачи](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=3716&chapterid=3627))
А вот что у меня получилось:

```
n = int(input())
x = float(input())
i = 0
i = float(i)
while n >= 0 and n < 21:
    coef = float(input())
    n = n - 1
    i = i + coef
    i = i * x
    if n == 0:
        break
    else:
        pass
coef = float(input())
i = i + coef
print(i)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как выполнить несколько проверок введенных пользователем данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571718/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Валидацию входных значений лучше делать отдельно от бизнес-логики:

```
   if (n < 0 || n > 20):
     sys.exit("Incorrect n value")
```

Например:

```
n = int(input())
if n < 0 or n > 20:
  sys.exit("Incorrect n value")

x = float(input())
a = float(input())
result = a
for i in range(0, n):
    a = float(input())
    result *= x
    result += a

print result
```